# Append data from list to excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to work with excel on python.

I have a list i want to add each value inside it in excel file, my current code:

```
for y in myzoo:
  loo1 = str(y)
  c5a = my_sheet.cell(row= 21 , column = 3)
  c5a.value = loo1
```

myzoo is the list (its originally a pyodbc.Row)
and i convert each entry to string, then save it to excel file, the problem is currently it save only last one overwriting all earlier values, i want to do one of two: save each value in next empty cell in row, or even (which less preferable) saving all the exported data into the cell without deleting earlier ones, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just do something like this:

```
column = 3  # start column
while myzoo:
    c5a = my_sheet.cell(row=21, column=column)
    if not c5a.value:
        c5a.value = str(myzoo.pop(0))
    column += 1
```

in case you need to preserve myzoo - you will need to copy it. (`temp = myzoo.copy()`)

Comment: Thank you! its worked, just needed to modify it little bit to look like this:
`code`
for y in myzoo:
  
  ro = 21
  while myzoo:
   c5a = my_sheet.cell(row= ro , column = 3)
   if not c5a.value:
     c5a.value = str(myzoo.pop(0))
   ro += 1
 'code'